# jQuery Path - Circular Path

Tags: jquery, path, geometry

I'm trying to get a circle path created with 4 points on it. One each at 90deg. so that eventually when I click a next button it will essentially just rotate around in a perfect circle.

I feel like i'm close but I just cant seem to nail it.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
var screenWidth = $(window).width();

$.fn.scrollPath("getPath")
    .arc(10, 10, 900, Math.PI/2, 0, true, {rotate: Math.PI/2 })
    .arc(0, 10, 0, Math.PI/2, 0, true, {rotate: Math.PI/2 })
$(".wrapper").scrollPath({drawPath: true}); // , wrapAround: true
}
```

**FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7e9Wm/**

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. scrolling the mouse moves the path around in a weird manner, but I can't see anything that might be a circle?

Comment: @caspian I'm trying to get it so that when I click, or scroll it moves around a circle. Eventually there will be picture of the world and then when I scroll or click things will fly around it etc..

Answer (score 0):

You are including the demo javascript file, removing this will allow you to actually begin building your path.

To setup a scroll path, you need to be aware of how the HTML5 Arc works.[image]

An arc is nothing more than a section of the circumference of an imaginary circle. This imaginary circle can be defined by x, y, and radius.  The start and end angles are multiples of PI, as shown in the image.

As a result your code should look something like

```
$.fn.scrollPath("getPath")
// arc( centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterclockwise [,options] )
.arc(0, 0, 180, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI , true, {rotate: Math.PI/2, name: "alpha"})
.arc(0, 0, 180, Math.PI, Math.PI/2, true, {rotate: Math.PI/2, name: "beta" })
.arc(0, 0, 180, Math.PI/2, 0, true, {rotate: Math.PI/2, name: "delta" })
.arc(0, 0, 180, 0, Math.PI * 1.5, true, {rotate: Math.PI/2, name: "gamma" });
```

See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rhuc3/